# Is it coincidence that every time someone loses one of the Deathly Hallows, they die immediately after?

Tags: harry-potter, deathly-hallows

When the Gaunts lost the Resurrection Stone, when James gave Dumbledore the Invisibility Cloak, when Dumbledore was disarmed by Draco, they all died shortly after. Which raises the question--was Dumbledore aware that taking James' Cloak would doom him? Or is it all just coincidence?

Comment: Harry lost the stone and he still lived for long afterwards

Comment: Grindelwald lost the Death-Stick and lived to a ripe old age in a prison.

Comment: Dumbledore gave the cloak to Harry and lived for another six years.

Comment: If Harry had died after leaving his Cloak at the top of the Astronomy Tower in book one then it would've been a much shorter series...

Comment: @RichS He decided to go home and re-think his life.

Comment: Dumbledore was disarmed by Draco, but Draco was disarmed by Harry. Draco Malfoy survived the experience.

Answer (score 21):

### No, it is *not even happening*

You've only listed the instances where someone dies after having lost possession of a Deathly Hallow, but you've neglected to list *all* instances where someone loses possession of a Deathly Hallow.

#### Resurrection Stone

- Cadmus Peverell down to Marvolo Gaunt
  Cadmus killed himself to be with his (dead) true love. He left the stone to his descendants. It ultimately ended up with Marvolo Gaunt.
  *Inherited after death (for generations).*
- Marvolo Gaunt to Morfin Gaunt
  Died shortly after serving his sentence in Azkaban; left the stone to his son, Morfin.
  *Inherited after death.*
- Morfin Gaunt to Tom Riddle jr.
  Tom Riddle jr. stole the ring containing the Resurrection Stone from Morfin, after framing him for the murder of Riddle's muggle family. Morfin was sentenced to life in Azkaban, where he died.
  *Died after losing it; unsure of time span*.
- Voldemort to Albus Dumbledore
  Voldemort used the ring to make his second Horcrux. Dumbledore travelled to the old Gaunt residence and dug up the ring from under the floor boards. Voldemort was defeated in battle about a year later.
  *Died after losing it.*
- Albus Dumbledore to Harry Potter
  Dumbledore left the ring containing the Stone to Harry in his will.
  *Inherited after death.*

#### Cloak of Invisibility

- Ignotus Peverell down to James Potter
  The Cloak was handed down the generations of descendants of Ignotus Peverell, until it ended up with James Potter.
  *Inherited after death (for generations).*
- From James Potter to Albus Dumbledore
  James loaned the Cloak to Dumbledore. He is killed by Voldemort shortly afterwards.
  *Died after losing it.*
- From Albus Dumbledore to Harry Potter
  Dumbledore gave Harry his rightful family heirloom. Dumbledore lived for years afterwards.
  *Did not die shortly after losing it.*

#### Elder Wand

- From Antioch Peverell to an unknown wizard
  Antioch was murdered in his sleep, the Elder Wand stolen.
  *Died **before or during** losing it.*
- From Emeric the Evil to Egbert the Egregious
  Egbert defeated ("slaughtered") Emeric in a duel.
  *Died **during** losing it.*
- From Mykew Gregorovitch to Gellert Grindelwald
  Grindelwald stunned Gregorovitch and made off with the wand. Gregorovitch lived for years afterwards, since Victor Krum was able to procure one of his last wands.
  *Did not die shortly after losing it.*
- From Gellert Grindelwald to Albus Dumbledore
  Dumbledore defeated Grindelwald, who was imprisoned for over 50 years afterwards.
  *Did not die shortly after losing it.*
- From Albus Dumbledore to Draco Malfoy
  During the Battle of the Astronomy Tower, Draco disarmed Dumbledore and gained (unbeknownst to him) possession of the Elder Wand. Dumbledore died during the battle, being killed by Snape.
  *Died shortly after losing it.*
- From Draco Malfoy to Harry Potter
  Harry disarmed Draco and gained possession of the Elder Wand. Draco lived for years afterwards, as evidenced by the epilogue where Harry and Draco both see their kids off to Hogwarts.
  *Did not die shortly after losing it.*

### Conclusion

As you can see, the Elder Wand is often violently taken, the death of the previous owner being part of that process. As such, those aren't instances where the previous owner dies *after* losing it.
The Cloak of Invisibility was handed down the line of descendants. The only instance where the owner dies after (temporarily) losing possession of it, is James Potter.
The Resurrection Stone was handed down from generation to generation as well, until the last of the Gaunts. The only instances of someone dying after losing it, are arguably Morfin Gaunt and Voldemort.

So no, it is not a coincidence — it's not even happening. You were cherry-picking the data.

Comment: You should include that Harry "lost" the invisibility cloak several times throughout the books. For example, in Philosopher's Stone, they "lost" (forgot) the cloak at the top of the astronomy tower after delivering Norbert to Charlie. Might want to look at other times, too. Also, Harry "lost" (dropped) the resurrection stone in the forest before confronting Voldy. Suggested from the comments in the Q.

Comment: @KevinFee I'll look into it, but I doubt that it will change the conclusion.

Comment: And one of those times, Professor Snape has acquired the invisibility cloak too, but he didn't die till much later.